# gVim ProportinalResize error

Tags: vim, plugins, resize, split

I have the ProportionalResize plugin installed, but it throws the following error message (shown below) everytime I resize the whole `GUI-WINDOW` after performing a window split. I realize this is a `Ingo Karkat` plugin which makes use of the `ingo-library` (I use `L9` as func library). But even with his lib installed the error message changes from
[image]
to
[image].

There is a comment in [`this`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ProportionalResize/blob/master/autoload/ProportionalResize.vim) and [`this`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ProportionalResize/blob/master/autoload/ProportionalResize/Record.vim) file about the `stale window dimensions` (comment on `revision 1.00.003`). Can't say I understand what he talks about. Just stumbled upon it.

If you need my vimrc, let me know.

Comment: You could try writing to Ingo. He's pretty helpful.

Comment: I believe he's very active on stack too. But good idea. Generally I refrain from bothering devs directyl ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin author here. I concur with the commenters that issues like these are best first addressed directly to the plugin's author (in my case, via the email address found in the documentation and scripts, since I don't use an issue tracker for these small plugins yet), not via Stack Overflow.

Because there is no `VimResizedPre` event, the plugin periodically (on `CursorHold`) records the current dimensions to be able to calculate the difference. When there's no current record, you'll get the `Stale window dimensions record` error. To avoid that, try waiting for 4 seconds before attempting the resize.

Resizing internal window splits (as you've reported) should not trigger that error, however, because the plugin is only triggered when the outer Vim window borders change, not when you adapt the internal window layout.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Waiting 4 seconds after doing the split (before resizing the whole window) triggers no error. Guess I was a bit hasty. My description might be misleading: I don't get an error while changing the size of internal windows, only when touching the gui-window.

Comment: Ah, okay, that clarifies things. So you do a `:split` and immediately after resize the Vim window?! The necessary delay is unfortunate, but due to Vim limitations. If you do the split via a mapping, you could try wrapping it in `:ProportionalResize split`, or append a `:doautocmd CursorHold`.

Comment: Yes, I do a lot of TeX stuff and I usually begin with setting up my working environment and not with opening the files. But I like the idea of mapping the split command. I'll stick with that. Thank you.